# Google Dynamic Remarketing Excessive View Thru Conversions

Tags: google, google-ads, marketing, remarketing

We run several ecommerce sites that we had previously set up with tag-based remarketing. We created a new dynamic remarketing campaign and only tagged the product page to see how dynamically created lists would populate.

Several of the dynamic lists began populating with more members than we had visitors to the store. There have also been more view through conversions than actual orders for that store. I have to think that because the dynamic remarketing seems to use a shared tag, and that tag isn't substantially different from our old remarketing tags, that it is errantly including all visitors and conversions for all stores in the lists (even though we haven't updated the tracking codes).

Is anyone else experiencing this? How can we stop conversions from being counted from multiple stores?